# Is it reasonable to use an empty conditional while loop after MPI_Recv?

Tags: c, mpi

Is it reasonable to use an empty `while` loop after `MPI_Recv` to wait a result from another processor to be sent? I want to make sure that the processor NEVER continues before receiving the result completely, as the following:

```
int recvBuffer = 0;

MPI_Recv(&recvBuffer, 1, MPI_INT, src, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); // recvBuffer expects to receive an integer greater than 0
while(recvBuffer == 0);
sum+= recvBuffer;
```

Answer (score 7):

No this isn't reasonable at all and strictly serves nothing. This is a blocking receive.
What you should do, is checking the return of the function. *That* gives you an indication of an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I know then if MPI_Recv has REALLY received something? Can I see an example of how to test the returning value as you suggested. THANK YOU

Comment: As I said, this is a blocking call. It doesn't return to the calling function, unless something was received. It would be a good idea to look up in the manual page about the errors that the function may return and then act upon these errors accordingly.

Comment: And let's add for completeness that it would also not be a good idea even after a nonblocking receive, where you still need to use `MPI_Wait*`for completion.